# Can I apply <script> tag and <link> tag JUST for certain lines of code in html?

Tags: html, css, tags

I have been using boostrap 4.0 to build my website.

A newly added item requires me to use boostrap 3.3.

But after adding the boostrap 3.3 css stylesheet, the collapse/exapnd nav bar is having trouble functioning normally.

So I am thinking to use JS to apply script tag and link tag to an item with certain ID. Is that possible? Thank you.

It would be a disaster to rewrite the newly added item :(

Comment: You will probably have to pull out the css you need from the 3.3 stylesheet, modify to target a specific id, and then bring it in your own css sheet. Bringing in the entire 3.3 css sheet for 1 element is excessive in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Certain css and js components can be downloaded separately here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

For example, if you want to use only bs X3 css for grid only you can uncheck all and then check "Grid system". You can also modify bs css by adding an extra class in front of the classes in order to make them unique.

Example ( adding a .bs-3 class for every X3 bootstrap class - it can be easily done if you download the sass files ) so wherever you use bootstrap classes along with your new class it should override the X4 classes.

```css
.bs-3.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your customize boostrap site, I simply changed the boostrap js file, and it all works fine now! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is against how CSS is designed to work (applying the style to the whole site). Now, this is possible with components, like the ones provided in most frameworks that create a limiting scope for CSS and JS.

Native [HTML components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components.) are not widely used nowadays.

If it is only a component, migrating it from Boostrap 3 to 4 should not be a big deal. There are not high design changes as we have between Bootstrap 3 and 4.

Other options are using the SAAS source of Boostrap 3 and rename the classes you use and add only them, but I think this would be much more work.

Comment: My code works fine now after adding a customized boostrap js file. Thanks for your answer anyway. It is a way to solve the problem. ;)